# Getting SyntaxError in javascript/application.js when setting rails project to use importmaps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, importerror

I'm trying to move a rails 7 project from using esbuild to using importmaps and getting the following error:

```
// app/javascript/application.js
import '@hotwired/turbo-rails'; // <-- Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
import 'controllers';
```

I've run and rerun `bundle exec rails importmap:install` a bunch of times already and compared all relevant files that I know of with a project where importmaps work.

For obvious reasons, adding `"type": "module",` to `package.json` is not an option (I don't have a package.json).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shamefully posting the solution in case anyone ever runs into the same problem:

We're using namespaces in the project and I forgot to include the `javascript_importmap_tags` tag in every namespaced layout file.

Comment: Thank you for following up.  You probably saved at least an hour of digging here.